# Why does &this_type::px from boost::smart_ptr return 1?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I am following the file `boost/smart_ptr/detail/operator_bool.hpp` and come across the following snippet of code that I do not understand

```
typedef T * this_type::*unspecified_bool_type;

operator unspecified_bool_type() const // never throws
{
    return px == 0? 0: &this_type::px;
}
```

I write some test codes with XCode and `&this_type::px` always return 1.  Why?

Can some C++ guru share your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

This is a little trick known as the [Safe Bool Idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

The problem is that if you write a conversion operator to `bool`:

```
operator bool() const;
```

Then it can be used in some tricky situations, for example: `1 + sharedp` with `bool` getting promoted to `int`... stupid eh ?

Therefore, the trick is to use a type that can be converted to `bool` but on which all other operations will provoke an error during compilation. The recommended way is to use a pointer-to-member in the class, and it is `typedef`ed to an explicit name so that error messages are a bit more understandable.

---

With C++11, this trick is obsolete, because the `explicit` qualifier can be applied to conversion operator:

```
explicit operator bool() const { return px; }
```

much more pleasant, isn't it ?

Comment: It may sound like an oxymoron, but C++11 solution may be called *`explicit` implicit* conversion function. +1 btw!

Comment: "With C++11, this trick is obsolete" -- not entirely (as I understand it), not if you do want to allow implicit conversions to `bool` (let's say for assignment to a `bool` object), but reject the arithmetic you mentioned.

Comment: @hvd: well, implicit assignment to `bool` has never been the primary concern here, mostly it has to do with `if (ptr)` idiomatic tests. But you are right that it could still be used to allow this implicit conversion.

Comment: @MatthieuM. If you can do `if (t) ...`, you should be able to rework it to `bool check = t; somethingElse(); if (check) ...` when that's appropriate, IMO. But I'll agree that's not the way it's mostly used, so it may be a small inconvenience.

Comment: @hvd: personally I often use `if (T* t = /* ... */)`, very handy to be sure not to execute anything on `t` if it's null, since it's only in scope when it's not.

Comment: @hvd: I wonder if there's a case to be made for `template <typename T> bool evaluate(T &t) { return static_cast<bool>(t); }`. Then your reworked code reads `bool check = evaluate(t);`. It has the added benefit of loudly flagging that `t` has been evaluated: any side-effects of `somethingElse()` won't affect the conditional, so hopefully make people more likely to question whether or not it's equivalent to `somethingElse(); if (t) ...;`. Of course you could just write the `static_cast<bool>` every time.

Comment: @SteveJessop Interesting idea. I think I like that better than casting to `bool` every time.

Comment: Come to think of it, you can write `bool check(t);` with an explicit conversion operator, can't you? Wins for brevity if you can.

Comment: @SteveJessop: yes, or even `bool check{t};` to use the new syntax. An `explicit` conversion operator is exactly like an `explicit` constructor in this regard. The only bonus (I think) is that some contexts (`if`, `while`, ...) are considered explicit too.

Answer (score 1):

`&this_type::px` is a trick used to obtain a boolean value equivalent to `true`.

Since boost does not use the `bool` type, but instead does not specifies what it is, it uses a pointer-to-member cast which always return the equivalent representation of `true` for an existing member (i.e. not `nullptr` or something cast from `0`).

See 4.12:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to
>   member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool.

The boolean conversion of pointer-to-members always happen in an integral context because there is no cast from pointer-to-member to an integer in C++.

Answer (score 1):

It is not 1, but it is output by ostream as 1 (bool) if you havent switched on boolalpha flag. ostream has no special output operator for member pointers.